# Why h.getresponse() is needed in python logging HTTPHandler?

Tags: python, logging, httphandler

I overrided the method `emit` of **python logging httphandler** to adapt it to my needs, and I noticed the line

```py
h.getresponse()    #can't do anything with the result
```

- Why is this line necessary?

I noticed that removing this line has no effect when using unsecure logging, but makes the logs fail when using secure connection.

```py
def emit(self, record):
        """
        Emit a record.
        Send the record to the Web server as a percent-encoded dictionary
        """
        try:
            import http.client, urllib.parse
            host = self.host
            if self.secure:
                h = http.client.HTTPSConnection(host, context=self.context)
            else:
                h = http.client.HTTPConnection(host)
            url = self.url
            data = urllib.parse.urlencode(self.mapLogRecord(record))
            if self.method == "GET":
                if (url.find('?') >= 0):
                    sep = '&'
                else:
                    sep = '?'
                url = url + "%c%s" % (sep, data)
            h.putrequest(self.method, url)
            # support multiple hosts on one IP address...
            # need to strip optional :port from host, if present
            i = host.find(":")
            if i >= 0:
                host = host[:i]
            # See issue #30904: putrequest call above already adds this header
            # on Python 3.x.
            # h.putheader("Host", host)
            if self.method == "POST":
                h.putheader("Content-type",
                            "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                h.putheader("Content-length", str(len(data)))
            if self.credentials:
                import base64
                s = ('%s:%s' % self.credentials).encode('utf-8')
                s = 'Basic ' + base64.b64encode(s).strip().decode('ascii')
                h.putheader('Authorization', s)
            h.endheaders()
            if self.method == "POST":
                h.send(data.encode('utf-8'))
            h.getresponse()    #can't do anything with the result
        except Exception:
            self.handleError(record)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getresponse()` call guarantees that the request is actually sent to the server by getting the response to the request.

Comment: But nothing is done with that response. What happends if the response never comes back?

Comment: If there is e.g. a network error or something, there should be an exception raised. There's nothing useful that can be done with the response, which is effectively just an acknowledgement that the server received the request with the event information.

Comment: Ok. That would explain why in our unit test the execution gets hanged. Probably our mock server is not responding correctly.